# Run Powershell commands from Powerbuilder?

Tags: powershell, powerbuilder

Following PowerShell commands send email. How do i use these commands in PowerBuilder?

```
$EmailFrom = "frt@gmail.com" 
$EmailTo = "ha@gmail.com" 
$Subject = "Notification from XYZ" 
$Body = "this is a notification from XYZ Notifications.." 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("frt@gmail.com", "mypass123"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this post](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/19/calling-net-assemblies-from-powerbuilder-classic-win32-via-powershell/) from Bruce Armstrong on the old SAP PowerBuilder forum.  It shows how to invoke Powershell.exe and having it execute a command from a text file.

Comment: It does not look right when powershell exe file runs minimized. i dont know if there is  free activex control for powershell. is there any other way to run powershell commands without using the powershell executeable file?

Answer (score 0):

i used the similar approach as given in the link by Matt. It worked for me.

```
/// Powershell commands to send email with attachment are saved in a file and that file is given to 
/// powershell executeable file as parameter

Integer li_FileNum
String theCmd

li_FileNum = FileOpen("C:\Temp\cmd.ps1", LineMode!, Write!, LockWrite!, Replace!)

theCmd = "$fromaddress = ~""+SendFrom.Text+"~""
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$toaddress = ~""+SendTo.Text+"~""
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

///theCmd = "$bccaddress = ~""+"BCC"+"~""
///theCmd = "$CCaddress = ~""+"CC"+"~""

theCmd = "$Subject = ~""+Subject.Text+"~""
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$body = ~""+Msg.Text+"~""
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$attachment = ~""+TheFile.Text+"~""
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$smtpserver = ~"smtp.gmail.com~""
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd) 

theCmd = "$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$message.From = $fromaddress"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$message.To.Add($toaddress)"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

//theCmd = "$message.CC.Add($CCaddress)"
//FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

//theCmd = "$message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress)"
//FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$message.IsBodyHtml = $False"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$message.Subject = $Subject"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$message.Attachments.Add($attach)"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$message.body = $body"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$smtp.EnableSsl = $true"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

theCmd = "$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(~""+SendFrom.Text+"~", ~""+Password.Text+"~");"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)


theCmd = "$smtp.Send($message)"
FileWrite(li_FileNum, theCmd)

FileClose(li_FileNum)

int li_rc 
string ls_command 
string ls_directory 
ls_directory = "C:\temp"
ls_command = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "&' 
ls_command += " '" + ls_directory + "\cmd.ps1' " 
li_rc = Run ( ls_command, Minimized! )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to replace the dots "......" with a string that you create that contains your commands, here is what I use:

```
string ls_cmd
oleobject wsh
wsh=create oleobject

wsh.connecttonewobject("WScript.Shell")

ls_cmd='cmd /C powershell ......'

wsh.run(ls_cmd,0,false)
destroy wsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, specific to the problem given, is to use the mail functions of PowerBuilder.  It will work only if you have an client email compatible with MAPI:

```
mailSession         mSes
mailReturnCode      mRet
mailMessage         mMsg
mailFileDescription mAttach

// Create a mail session
mSes = create mailSession

// Log on to the session
mRet = mSes.mailLogon()

// Populate the mailMessage structure
mMsg.Subject = 'Mail subject'
mMsg.Recipient[1].name = 'to@someadress.com'
mMsg.Notetext = ''
mAttach.FileType = mailAttach!
mAttach.PathName = "yourpath"
mAttach.FileName =  "yourfile"
mAttach.Position = len(mMsg.notetext) - 1       
mMsg.AttachmentFile[1] = mAttach

// Send the mail
mRet = mSes.mailSend(mMsg)
IF mRet <> mailReturnSuccess! THEN
        MessageBox("Mail Send", "Error while sending message" )
       
END IF

// Cleanup
mSes.mailLogoff()
DESTROY mSes
```